# Can't get my function to run more than once and break my code

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to run this function until the player or the computer wins 5 times. Without the while loop, it runs one time and everything works fine. As soon as I add a while loop, the function still runs only once and it gives me an undefined return.

```js
function playToFive() {
  console.log('Let\'s play Rock Paper Scissors');
  var playerWins = 0;
  var computerWins = 0;
  while (playerWins === 5 || computerWins === 5) {
    if (humanVsMachine === 'player') {
      playerWins += 1;
    } else if (humanVsMachine === 'computer') {
      computerWins += 1;
    }
    return [playerWins, computerWins];
  }
}

console.log(playToFive());
```

Comment: return will terminate the loop

Comment: It will never enter the loop, since both playerWins andd computerWins starts at 0 and not 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(playerWins === 5 || computerWins === 5)
```

Your while loop will actually never execute, since you're checking for equality and both `playerWins` and `computerWins` are `0` initially.

You may be looking for a condition more like this:

```
while(playerWins < 5 && computerWins < 5)
```

Note that we're using the logical AND `&&` instead of the logical OR `||`. This is because you don't want to keep looping until both of them win. The logical OR means that even if the computer has won but the player hasn't, we'll continue looping. Only one of the conditions needs to be true for the whole statement to be true.

When we use the logical AND, if one of them is false (meaning, if only one player has reached 5 wins already), then we will break out of the loop as we should.

The next problem is that you have a return statement in your while loop, so after the first execution, even if 5 wins haven't been reached yet, it will return the array of the player's wins and the computer's wins.

You should put the return statement *after* the loop so that you run the loop 5 times and then return after somebody has won.

And finally, since you haven't provided the rest of the code, I'm not sure if `humanVsMachine` is actually defined; if you defined that outside of the function then you're good to go.

Comment: Oh man, no wonder this thing wasn't working. Thank you very very much Purag. That explanation was excellent.

Answer (score 2):

After the if-else structure is evaluated and executed, a `return` statement is called unconditionally, thus terminating the loop prematurely. You should place the `return` **after** the loop instead. Additionally, the loop condition should be as long as neither player reaches 5 wines (evaluated with the `<` operator):

```
while (playerWins < 5 && computerWins < 5 ) {
    if (humanVsMachine === 'player') {
        playerWins +=1;
    } else if (humanVsMachine === 'computer') {
        computerWins += 1;
    }
}
return [playerWins, computerWins];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move the `return` statement outside the while loop, but you'll also need to change your conditions on your `while` loop - right now it only runs if either `playerWins` or `computerWins` are exactly 5, when in fact it needs to stop running at that point (so `while(playerWins < 5 && computerWins < 5)`)

Answer (score 0):

**Return will terminate your loop**

```
function returnMe() {
  for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    if (i === 1) return i;
  }
}

alert(returnMe()); Try this out 


function playToFive() {
    console.log('Let\'s play Rock Paper Scissors');
    var playerWins = 0;
    var computerWins = 0;
    while (playerWins === 5 || computerWins === 5) {
        if (humanVsMachine === 'player') {
        playerWins += 1;
        } else if (humanVsMachine === 'computer') {
        computerWins += 1;
        }
    // return [playerWins, computerWins]; moving code to below
    }
    return [playerWins, computerWins]; // moved return outside the loop here
}

console.log(playToFive());
```

Comment: It never enters the loop

Answer (score 0):

You're returning inside the while loop, which will end the looping process. Therefore move your return code outside the loop like below. Also notice that your logical statement is not going to allow the loop to run properly.

```
function playToFive() {
    console.log('Let\'s play Rock Paper Scissors');
    var playerWins = 0;
    var computerWins = 0;
    while (playerWins < 5 && computerWins < 5 ) {
        if (humanVsMachine === 'player') {
        playerWins += 1;
        } else if (humanVsMachine === 'computer') {
        computerWins += 1;
        }
    // return [playerWins, computerWins]; moving code to below
    }
    return [playerWins, computerWins]; // moved return outside the loop here
}

console.log(playToFive());
```

Allow me to add that spacing your code helps a lot, it's a little bit 'vertical' looking with the closing brackets. Note how spacing on the above helps to visually identify things like this :)

Comment: I noted this and edited the answer, give a man sometime to write :)

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the detailed answer AGE.  I agree, I need to work on my spacing.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful, it's a good idea to put the time to make your code more readable, rather than to get stuck on the silly things.